# Using Django rest framework as a rest client

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a rest server that can be called e.g. with:

```
http://localhost:8080/myserver/rest/books/t1.json
```

I want to know how can I use from [django rest framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) as a client and call my rest server?

Comment: Do you want to provide a second API that calls the first API before delivering results or are you just looking to call an API programmatically?

Comment: I want to call programmatically the rest server and deserialize json/xml/yaml result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django Rest Framework is for *creating* REST APIs, not consuming them. To simply call a REST API from Django/Python you can do the following using `json` and `urllib2` which are standard:

```
import json
import urllib2

data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen('http://myapi.com/'))
```

or you can use the 3rd party library [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/):

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://myapi.com/')
r.json()
```