# Django rest framework: load model data into serializer maually (to then send it as an HTTP payload / webhook)

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

So we have a post-save signal that calls a celery task that is using requests to notify one of our partners about an order by a user he has referred to us.
I would like the payload to equal the detail view output of the order.

So far so good.

However, for test-ability purposes and also to avoid unnecessary HTTP calls, I would like to retrieve the instance from the DB (in the celery task), feed it to the serializer (OrderDetailSerializer) and then call `requesst.post` with `serializer.data`

What is the easiest way to achieve that

The closest question to this one I found is this
[Using Django rest framework as a rest client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27046898/using-django-rest-framework-as-a-rest-client)

The answer suggested to use simple JSON serialization. However, it is not a good solution for us because the serializer hides some sensitive data and ads some nested data via NestedSerializers.

Serializer code

```
class OrderDetailSerializer(OrderSerializer):

    price = RateSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)
    payment_url = PrivateField(public_return_value=None)

    class Meta(MetaFlatOrder):
        fields = \
            MetaFlatOrder.fields + RATE_FIELDS + FIAT_FIELDS + DETAIL_FIELDS
```

Note: `OrderSerializer instanceof serializers.ModelSerializer`

Comment: You can just pass the instance to the serializer? `OrderDetailSerializer(instance).data`?

Comment: /pipeline/source/orders/serializers/base.py in get_attribute(self, instance)
     20         # being logged in (such as conswitch)
     21         if instance.user.orders.all().count() < 2 \
---> 22                 or instance.user == self.context['request'].user:

Comment: e.g. keyerror request. as I've mentioned the env is a celery process

Comment: Suppose I could mock the request.user to be order.user, but would it do it?

Comment: Can you add the serializer to your question? A serializer should probably not require a request object

Comment: And the base class `OrderSerializer`?

Comment: Just inherits from `serializers.ModelSerializer` and defines some fields, no specialties observed

Comment: Passing an instance to a serializer shouldn't require a request obj, I'm testing it now and it works fine. How are you passing the instance to the serializer?

Comment: In [36]: OrderDetailSerializer
Out[36]: orders.serializers.instant.OrderDetailSerializer

In [37]: o1
Out[37]: <Order: UNCONFIRMED PAYMENT BUY ODGC7X ETHEUR 0.93031778 ETH 100 EUR AnonymousUser>

In [38]: OrderDetailSerializer(o1).data

Comment: And no output or is the result the `KeyError`? The issue is wherever the line of code that contains `self.context['request'].user` is? It appears to be something in your project can you share it and the full traceback

Comment: https://codecollab.io/@proj/SnailsStoryGray

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227746/discussion-between-oleg-belousov-and-iain-shelvington).